# Dog sudden aggressive towards dogs shes played with before

Tags: behavior, training

We adopted a 2 month old female lab mix 1 year ago. she's always been extremely friendly toward all dogs shes met. We have a dog park at our apartment complex that she used to love playing with other dogs in. 2 months ago we adopted a 2 month old shepherd mix. Both dogs are sprayed. Sienna who is now 1 year and 4 months old is great with the new puppy, never too rough or aggressive; however in the past 3 weeks Sienna has become very aggressive towards the dogs in the dog park that she used to play with. She has started 3 fights with different dogs now. So far I am just not taking her into the dog park anymore. Any idea or suggestions on what I can do to stop this behavior?

Comment: Is there something that triggers the aggression? E.g. the other dog getting close to the puppy?

Comment: Not that I can see, the new puppy is no where near the dogs that she attacks. One time the other dog has a ball in its mouth and my dog tried taking it away and then attack, so that was definitely the ball. But she used to  play all the time with other dogs and toys and she never cared when another dog had a toy.